# The select box value never gets submited into the database - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When I am posting a value into the database using the `<input>` tag it works flawlessly, but when I am using the `<select>` dropdown box function instead, it never posts the 1st value, when I select the 2nd value from the `<select>` tag, only then the value gets posted into the database. I'm just unable to spot the issue. Please help me here, down below I'm entering the source-code for the select box dropdown as well as the input option along with the controller which is responsible to store the value into the database.

[image]

Select Dropdown Option Code

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="sub_category_id" class="block">Sub-Category ID</label>
    <select wire:model="sub_category_id" name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_id" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900">
        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->sub_category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
    </select>
</div>
```

Input Option Code

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="sub_category_id" class="block">Sub-Category ID</label>
    <input wire:model="sub_category_id" type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-blue-900" placeholder="Input Sub-Category ID">
    @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
</div>
```

Livewire Controller:- App\Http\Livewire\MenuItemList

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\MasterMenu;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\SubCategory;
use App\Models\MenuItem;

class MenuItemList extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search;
    public $itemId,$sub_category_id,$item_name,$item_description;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    public function render() {   
        $subcategories = SubCategory::all();
        $searchParams = '%'.$this->search.'%';

        return view('livewire.master-menu.menu-item-list', compact('subcategories'), [
            'menuitemlist' => MenuItem::where('item_name','like', $searchParams)->latest()->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }

    public function showModal() {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function hideModal() {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function store() {
        $this->validate(
            [   
                'sub_category_id' => 'required',
                'item_name' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        MenuItem::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->itemId], [
            'sub_category_id' => $this->sub_category_id,
            'item_name' => $this->item_name,
            'item_description' => $this->item_description
        ]);

        $this->hideModal();

        session()->flash('info', $this->itemId ? 'Post Update Successfully' : 'Post Created Successfully' );

        $this->itemId = '';
        $this->sub_category_id = '';
        $this->item_name = '';
        $this->item_description = '';
    }

    public function edit($id) {
        $menuitem = MenuItem::findOrFail($id);
        $this->itemId = $id;
        $this->sub_category_id = $menuitem->sub_category_id;
        $this->item_name = $menuitem->item_name;
        $this->item_description = $menuitem->item_description;

        $this->showModal();
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        MenuItem::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('delete','Post Successfully Deleted');
    }
}
```

Comment: Open console, check errors there.

Comment: Thanks mate, just installed telescope.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, its a bug with the livewire, which was never fixed. The preselected value or the 1st option which is selected by default never posts the value to the database or the server.

Get around it in two ways.

Add a disabled "Select" option with value "" to all selects.

Preselect the first value in mount.

Here is the link to the discussion, https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/85